# Keras Conv2D parameter order

Tags: keras

If I have a layer with 32 convolution 5x5 rgb kernels in it, I would expect the shape to be  (32, 5, 5, 3) being (count, h, w, rgb) but instead it is 
(5, 5, 3, 32).  This messes up iteration since

```
for kern in kernels:
```

Does not work correctly. I get a series of (5 ,3, 32) ndarrays. I do not get each of the 5x5 rgb kernels.
Am I just doing this wrong?

Comment: out of curiosity, why are you doing this?

Comment: Doing a custom kernel generation to get a CNN that is not trained with back propagation so unlabeled data can be used.  Then after-the-fact labeling takes place.  On other words, generating the maximally different kernels for the entire training image set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange that the `kernel` is stored in the shape `(h, w, channels, filters)`, as the [implementation](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/convolutional.py#L360) suggests otherwise:

```
kernel_shape = self.kernel_size + (self.filters, input_dim)
self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=kernel_shape, ...)
...
```

However, if this is what you are seeing, and if you need to iterate over each filter, why not just move the axis with [`np.moveaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html):

```
kernel = np.moveaxis(kernel, -1,0)
```

to get the desired `(kernels, h, w, channels)`.